# How come when changing coordinates you do the opposite rotation you want?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, rotations

[image: Graph]

[image: Linear Algebra Changing Coordinates Problem]

How come when solving this problem they decide that the *B coordinate vector of **v*** is

\begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{bmatrix} and not \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} ?
Deciding which one is which completely changes the answer of the problem.

Also on the right side of the picture I thought of another way to do it, since \begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \end{bmatrix} is just rotated 45 degrees counter clockwise from the original x and y so I just put a 45 degree rotation matrix multiplied by the original coordinates. Then I would solve this for x' and y' and plug them back in the original equation and then I would get the equation of the graph in the form of the standard coordinate system, but this does not work and when I plot it, the ellipse is rotated 45 degrees clockwise and not counterclockwise.

So I am not quite sure why this method does not work, nor do I understand how was the books logic in deciding which vector to be the B coordinate vector of V.

Comment: It is reasonable that you find something confusing here: "choosing a basis" and "coordinates with respect to a basis" are (in a sense that is not so elementary) "dual", which leads to the sort of seeming paradox you have found: is the matrix $A$, or is it $A$-transpose?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question about the B coordinates, $x’$ and $y’$ are the definitions of the new coordinates.  The rest of the problem is then to transform $x$ and $y$ to $x’$ and $y’$ because you are transferring the coordinate system from $v$ to $[v]_B$.  The reason you need a $-45$ degree rotation instead of a $45$ degree rotation is because you are rotating the coordinate system to an ellipse that is already rotated 45 degrees.  This is similar to rotating the ellipse $-45$ degrees in the original coordinate system.